# Using a crate errors with "linking with cc failed", while building its source project succeeds

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-crates

I'm trying to import an external crate in a simple hello world application.

In the *main.rs*, it was wrote

```
use rustdds::*;
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

`cargo build` then errors with

```
user@xxx:~/Documents/dds_test:$ cargo build
   Compiling num-traits v0.2.14
   Compiling num-integer v0.1.44
   Compiling num-iter v0.1.42
   Compiling mio-extras v2.0.6
   Compiling rand v0.7.3
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1
```

I had already added the line `rustdds = "0.4.8"` below `[dependencies]` in *Cargo.toml*:

```
[dependencies]
rustdds = "0.4.8"
```

How could this be fixed?

Btw, I checked my `gcc --version` and it was the latest version. I also tried to download the crate's source project and `cargo build` the downloaded project and everything was fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the reason finally that my Rust version was not the latest.

Solution is to update `rustup`, i.e.,

```
rustup update
```